# Ruby aggregate function with model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, aggregate

I have a product model in my ruby on rails application which has name,endorsement and expense attributes.

I need to write a query that list all records, but for every record I need to calculate endorsement-expense as income value. That seems to be ok. However, I need to sum all of the incomes consequtively as well.

For example my records are like these:

---

```
Name Endorsement Expense
X    100         25
Y    20          17
X    60          55  
T    178         78
```

I need to list those values as:

---

```
Name Endorsement Expense Income  Total Income
X    100         25      75      75
Y    20          17      3       78
X    60          55      5       83 
T    178         78      100     183
```

How can I do that ?

Thanks.

Comment: Where are these other numbers magically coming from?

Comment: Store the total in a variable, and add each income as you loop through the records?

Comment: `total = 0; records.each { |r| ....; total += r.income}`

Answer (score 1):

```
rows = Product.select('name,endorsement,expense, (endorsement-expense) as income')

total_income = 0
rows.each do |row|
  total_income += row.income
  puts "#{row.name}, #{row.endorsement}, #{row.expense}, #{row.income}, #{total_income}"
end
```

Comment: That should be `#{total_income}`, not `#{r.total_income}`

Comment: It will be more reusable if income is an instance method.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it with a total income for each product:

```
products = Product.select("(endorsement - expense) AS 'income', name, endorsement, created_at, null as total") 
products.each do |p|
   p.total = Product.select("sum(endorsement) - sum(expense) AS 'total'").where(name: p.name).where("created_at <= ?", p.created_at).group('name').last.total
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can apply [inject](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject) function to accumulate total income.

It will look something like this:

```
products.inject{|sum, product| sum += (product.endorsement - product.expense }
```